# Less vspace when using \begin{multicols}{n}

Tags: tikz-pgf, multicol

I have made these box environments, which looks like this:
[image]

The problem is that there is more vertical space between the text and the box than I want it to be. I tried to shorten the gap between the box and the text, but to no use. I think it may be because of some aspect with the `multicols` environment because without the environment the gap is much shorter.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xspace}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\geometry{footskip=2cm,left=2.2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=4.3cm,rmargin=4cm}
\begin{document}

\newenvironment{notes}
    {\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep\fcolorbox{black}{white}}%

    \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}
    \noindent{ }\begin{multicols}{3}\raggedcolumns%
    \vspace{0.1cm}
    \noindent\hspace{-0.15cm}}
    {\end{multicols}\vspace{0.2cm}\endMakeFramed}
\begin{notes}
    tehah sa d jsa  dsah fdksa f djs afhd safds ahf dsaf dsa hfd sa
     sdakjf dskjafjdsjka fjdsjkafjdsjafjdjs fak djsafkd sj afjdsja fd sjafdsa
     fd safd kjsafkjdsafkjd sjaf jd fd sa fd sajf kds af jds akj fdsa 
     fd skja fkjd sfa jds afjds ak sha dhs aj ds afd sa ds  shDSAD sa  HCDSH CDhj hjds ahd sa ds a ds ah dsa jd hsa d sa ds avjlfd hld sahf dlsa fhd saf dsahfdshfadsf dhs f jds jf dsfhd sf dh fsfh ds fd s fjds f dh hs fh ds fjds f hdfsdshfd h fds fd s f djs hafd kfadjsahfdnbafds a df di ff f r fh frhuf hrf  fr fiu hfe fhfdsfds hfds kj kjfd fs kdfsf jds f ds js ks jfkd sds
\end{notes}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is your problem solved? If yes, then consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTFM? `multicols` inserts `\multicolsep` before and after the environment body.

```
\newenvironment{notes}
    {\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep\fcolorbox{black}{white}}%   
    \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}%
    \setlength\multicolsep{0pt}%
    \begin{multicols}{3}\raggedcolumns
 %   \vspace{0.1cm}          % what is this doing?
 %   \noindent\hspace{-0.15cm}% what is this supposed to achieve? I guess this 
                              % should have been
     \noindent\ignorespaces
    }
    {\end{multicols}\endMakeFramed}
```